# Read a variable from file containing a nested variable from same file

Tags: linux, bash

I hope you are doing well.

I am a bit confused...

I have a file like:

```
var1:value1
var2:value2
...
varn:blabla/$var2/blabla
```

When I read the file, no problem I can get all lines, and instantiate all the variables.

In brief this is what I do in a function:

```
while IFS=":" read -r f1 f2
do
    if [ ! -z $f1 ] && [ ! -z $f2 ]; then

        f2=eval $f2
        export $f1=$f2

    fi
done < $fileName
```

And it works well except for `varn...`

I get `blabla/$var2/blabla`

instead of having:

```
blabla/value2/blabla...
```

and this makes my script failing to start a command since varn is supposed to be the path.

the real parameter file is:

```
<deleted some parameters>
version:1.7.0

MongoInstall:/apps/deliverable_${version}/mongo
```

during execution I get:

```
+ export 'MongoInstall=/ec/local/nasstat/apps/deliverable_${version}/mongo'
+ MongoInstall='/ec/local/nasstat/apps/deliverable_${version}/mongo'
```

...

and then...

```
+ '/apps/deliverable_${version}/mongo/installation_mongo_1.7.0.sh' env stop
./mongotransfer.sh: line 54: /apps/deliverable_${version}/mongo/installation_mongo_1.7.0.sh: No such file or directory
```

While I would expect to get:

```
/apps/deliverable_1.7.0/mongo/installation_mongo_1.7.0.sh
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes well spotted Stéphane. So, to read: varn:blabla/$var2/blabla

Comment: That `f2=eval $f2` line makes little sense. Also note that in `bash`, parameter expansions must be quoted. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: Are you sure this works? Are you really running `f2=eval $f2`? Did you mean `f2=$(eval "$f2")` maybe? Or something else? `f2=eval $f2` will first set the variable `f2` to the string `eval`, temporarily for the duration of the current command, and then will try to execute the original value of `$f2` as a command.

Comment: @terdon, `eval "$f1=\$f2"` or maybe `eval "$f1='$f2'"` would make more sense even if still dangerous and not foolproof.

Comment: I need f2 to be evaluated and then assigned to f1 which is then exported. Yes it works for all the variables except that one.

Comment: @user12877516 I... don't think it works. Maybe it isn't printing errors, but it can't be doing what you think it is doing. Not if that is really the code you have. `f2=eval $f2` is not evaluating `$f2`.

Comment: Some note here... f1 is supposed to be the variable to create and export with the content from f2 while reading parameters file lines.

Comment: OK, but what do you think the line `f2=eval $f2` is doing? As I said above, that sets the variable `f2` to the string `eval` and then executes the value of `f2` as a command. Try it: `f2='echo "I am f2"'; f2=eval $f2`. That will simply run `echo "I am f2"`. You are _not_ running the command `eval`, this cannot be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob -o nounset
unset MongoInstall
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line = (#b)([[:IDENT:]]##):(*) ]] &&
    : ${(P)match[1]::=${(e)match[2]}}
done < parameter-file
printf 'MongoInstall="%s"\n' $MongoInstall
```

Beware the `e` flag, like your `eval` will happily evaluate code in there. For instance, if the parameter file contains `var=$(reboot)`, it will reboot.

A safer approach, would be to do the expansions by hand:

```
MongoInstall=$(
  perl -wlne '
    if (/^(\w+):(.*)/) {
      $var = $1; $value = $2;
      $value =~ s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$var{$1}/g;
      $var{$var} = $value;
    }
    END {print $var{MongoInstall}}' < parameter-file
)
```

Or the same with `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob -o nounset
typeset -A vars
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = (#b)([[:IDENT:]]##):(*) ]]; then
    var=$match[1] value=$match[2]
    value=${value//(#b)\${([[:IDENT:]]##)}/$vars[$match[1]]}
    vars[$var]=$value
  fi
done < parameter-file
print -r -- $vars[MongoInstall]
```

In `bash`, maybe you intended to write:

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2
do
  if [ -n "$f1" ] && [ -n "$f2" ]; then
    eval "$f1=\"$f2\""
  fi
done < parameter-file
```

That assumes the lines of `parameter-file` doesn't contain `"`s and doesn't end in `:`. It makes no attempt to check that `$f1` contains a valid variable name or that in general `<contents-of-f1>="<contents-of-f2>"` forms valid `bash` code.

The `f2=eval $f2` in your code doesn't make sense, that attempts to run the command stored in `$f2` (subject to split+glob as not quoted) with `f2=eval` in its environment.

`export`ing the variables also serve no purpose other than polluting the environment of commands you'll run later.

Leaving parameter expansions unquoted is also incorrect in `bash`, especially with `[ -z` (`[ ! -z x ]` is `[ -n x ]` btw).

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately zsh is not an option. I run on bash 4.2.46 and I keep strictly bash approach so ... no sed, no awk, no perl...whatever. No external commands allowed.

Comment: @user12877516, you know a shell is a command line interpreter, a command whose whole purpose is to run other commands, right?

Comment: If you want "strictly no external commands" then zsh is a much better option @user12877516, since it includes many more facilities than bash which reduce the need for external commands.

Comment: Thank you Martin but this is not an option. And bash is great if we spend some time to get it. To be complete, I am surprised it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: @user12877516, also note that `export` is to flag a shell variable so it's passed in the environment of external commands that are executed. If you're not going to execute any command, exportings those variables is useless.

Comment: Stéphane, of course they are used. The goal was to move away all hardcoded variables from a script that must be started from Bamboo. But I want to keep pipeline clean, small and not end up with variables inside the tasks/jobs in Bamboo. In briefrief I do devops with bash and I created a kind of TDD framework in bash too so I can create and execute unit-tests and integration tests without specific framework. I work in vscode and I use task runner to automate unit-tests (not in this project yet) and I execute all remotely using ssh.